# Removing specific elements from a webpage with a script

Tags: javascript, html

I currently use :

"javascript:document.body.contentEditable%20=%20'true';%20document.designMode='on';%20void%200"

To remove certain elements of a webpage. The page is a monitoring view for several alarms. I am required to monitor only a portion of them. I have been using the above script to delete the views I don't need. I'm wondering if there is a better way than manually  "deleting" them every day.

Could I use the above script as a base to specify these elements and remove them all at once? I'm a bit of a rookie with this so any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you use chrome and install the "page eraser" extension. It allows you to permanently remove elements from any webpage.

Comment: I wanted to, but can't install it unfortunately.

Comment: Are you talking about just removing sections of a page in the browser (not permanent) for your viewing?

Comment: If you are using some kind of ad blocker, you could try filtering the unwanted elements as if they were ads

Comment: You could use Greasemonkey on Firefox. http://www.greasespot.net/

Comment: Yes, just removing the sections in the browser for my viewing. It doesn't need to be permanent, I'm more so looking to hide things I don't need so it isn't cluttered. It's do-able with the script I've been using. I would just like to be able to remove them all at once instead of selecting them individually. 

ie: If I have an alarm for every state in the USA, I need only monitor the NE. They are in alphabetical order. I'd like to remove the other states.

Comment: We need to see the page source in order to actually write the script that removes the unneeded elements.

Comment: @Rudy
Is there a preferred method for me to upload to Source? Don't imagine the character limit for comments would allow such a thing?  
Also, as a reference point, the Alarms present as .png that refresh. If I can just add the "bla.bla.net/blabla/img/del_30.png or what have you for each of the ones I need removed, to a known script of some sort... that would be sufficient for my end goal, I assume?

Comment: So I came up with doing this:
javascript: var image_x = document.getElementById('aus'); image_x.parentNode.removeChild(aus);
var image_x = document.getElementById('bak'); image_x.parentNode.removeChild(bak);
var image_x = document.getElementById('bhm'); image_x.parentNode.removeChild(bhm);
var image_x = document.getElementById('can'); image_x.parentNode.removeChild(can);

But It's hugely bulky and after I add too many lines, it stops working as a bookmark......  thoughts?

Comment: actually it failed because the last ID was 'for' so I'll just have to live what that one being there lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) on Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) on Chrome. Either you choose, the following script will work. You must install the extension in your browser. You then need to replace the URL from the script `http://yoursite.com/` with your URL, add all id's to the array, add the script to the extension and it will automatically do the work. No click on a bookmark necessary.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        CleanUp
// @namespace   cleanup
// @include     http://yoursitehere.com/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var removables = ['aus', 'bak', 'bhm', 'can'];//add more id's here following the pattern
for (var i = 0; i < removables.length; i++) {
  var element = document.getElementById(removables[i]);
  if (element) { 
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}
```

If you want to stick to the bookmarklet, I have adapted it for you:

```
javascript: function run() { var r = ['aus', 'bak', 'bhm', 'can']; for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) { var e = document.getElementById(r[i]); if (e) { e.parentNode.removeChild(e); } }; }; run();
```

Here too, you must update the list of id's to include all you want.

Comment: Greatly appreciated @Rudy.

Comment: @user8155484 Please accept my answer to close this question. I am happy to know my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

javascript: var image_x = document.getElementById('ID'); image_x.parentNode.removeChild(ID);

Edit the ID; Copy and Paste and edit as many times as are required. It's bulky and ugly for what I needed but it works as one Bookmark in Chrome.